# Browser doesn`t set cookies

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cors, react-apollo

I am making an app on react.js and i have an express-graphql server. I use jwt access and refresh tokens for authentification.On client-side I use Apollo for querys. And i dont know why but i cant set refresh token to my client-side app. I read a lot of posts on stackoverflow , cors docs and still not solve the problem.Both apps are working on localhost but on different ports.

**Here is my middleware connection**

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors(
    {
        credentials: true,
        origin: "*",
    }
))
```

**Here is Apollo links**

```
export const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri:  API_LINK + "/graphql",
});

export const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if(token && (Date.now() >= jwtDecode(token).exp * 1000)){
        return { headers: {
                ...headers,
            }}
    }
    if(!token){
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                withCredentials: true
            },
        };
    }
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
        },
    };
});

export const getNewToken = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(API_LINK + "/graphql", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: `
            mutation {
            refreshToken{
            type 
            token
                }
                }
                `
            })});
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

export const errorLink = onError(
    ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
        if(networkError?.statusCode === 401 || networkError?.statusCode === 500 ) {
            console.log(networkError)
            return fromPromise(
                getNewToken().then(({data}) =>{
                    console.log(data)
                    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.refreshToken.token)
                    return data.refreshToken.token
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(e)
                    return;
                })
            )
                .filter((value) => Boolean(value))
                .flatMap((accessToken) => {
                    const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
                    operation.setContext({
                        headers: {
                            ...oldHeaders,
                            authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                        },
                    });
                    return forward(operation);
                });
        }
        if (graphQLErrors){
            graphQLErrors.forEach(({message, locations, path}) =>{
                    if(message === "Помилка авторизації") {
                        return   fromPromise(
                            getNewToken().then((data) =>{
                                console.log(data)
                                if(!data?.refreshToken?.token){
                                    return null
                                }
                                localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data?.refreshToken?.token)
                                return data?.refreshToken?.token
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error)
                                return;
                            })
                        )
                            .filter((value) => Boolean(value))
                            .flatMap((accessToken) => {
                                const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
                                operation.setContext({
                                    headers: {
                                        ...oldHeaders,
                                        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                                    },
                                });
                                return forward(operation);
                            });
                    }
                    console.log(
                        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
                    )
            }
            );
        }


        if (networkError) {
            console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
        }
    }
);
```

**How I am sending cookies from server**

```
  res.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers" ,"Set-Cookie")
            res.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , httpOnly: true , secure: false})
```

And server are sending cookie and I can see it in my developer tools
[image: Server response headers]
**ApolloClient initialization**

```
const client  = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([errorLink , authLink, httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: true,
    credentials: "include"
})
```

Cookies [image]

Comment: `res.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie")` has no effect on the browser: `Set-Cookie` is a [forbidden response-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name).

Comment: Besides, `origin: "*"` is incompatible with credentialed requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards. Instead of `*`, you'll need to explicitly specify the allowed origin(s) in your CORS configuration.